# Scheme recursive unzip function for more than one list

Tags: function, scheme, unzip

I need help finishing up an unzip function which takes a zipped list and returns a list of two lists. The result I want is as follows...

```
(unzip '((a b) (1 2)))
'((a 1) (b 2))

(unzip '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)))
'((a b c) (1 2 3))

(unzip '(unzip '()))
'(() ())
```

I can get my code to work for the null case and with a list containing two lists, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make it recursive and work for more than 2 lists such as the second example.

```
(define (unzip l)
  (if (null? l) 
      '(() ())
      (map list (car l) (car (cdr l)))))
```

This will work fine for an empty list or two lists, but I have a hard time setting up the recursive part to work with three or possibly more lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty standard operation, it's equivalent to finding the transpose of a list of lists. It's usually implemented like this:

```
(define (unzip lst)
  (apply map list lst))
```

It'll work for the first two examples. The third, I believe is ill-defined, but if you want to make it work for that weird case, I'll leave that as an exercise ;)

Notice that if you `unzip` an unzipped list you get back the original input ... meaning that `unzip` is also `zip`!

```
(unzip '((a b) (1 2) (x y)))
=> '((a 1 x) (b 2 y))

(unzip '((a 1 x) (b 2 y)))
=> '((a b) (1 2) (x y))
```

Comment: Alright, I was pretty close. I knew I wanted to use map list, but was just a bit off. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
(apply map list '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5)))

;Value 16: ((a b c d e) (1 2 3 4 5))
```

this does it. BTW the same trick does it for *zipping* as well, provided all the lists are of the same length:

```
(apply map list (list '(a b c d e) '(1 2 3 4 5)))

;Value 17: ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5))
```

Comment: If you use SRFI 1, the lists don't need to be of the same length either: the mapping stops when the shortest list stops.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that in Scheme a function can return multiple values?

```
(define (unzip list)
  (values (map car  list)
          (map cadr list)))
```

and then use it like this:

```
(let-values ([(z1 z2) (unzip '((a 1) (b 2)))])       
   ;; Use z1 and z2
   ...)
```